# AngularJS and efficiency (or: storing values for multiple uses)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I recently started studying a bit of AngularJS (with almost no previous experiences in programming). I would like to create a tool for statistical analysis and to do so I worked on a few "proof-of-concept" examples.

Like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/nitecorp/udcjnoxo/

It works but I have the feeling that the way I am using the functions is highly inefficient:

```
<tr>
    <td>Average Age</td>
    <td>{{getAverage()}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Younger</td>
    <td>{{getStats(getAges())['younger']}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Older</td>
    <td>{{getStats(getAges())['older']}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Question**
What is the right approach to store getAges and use the results instead of recalculating every time? Same for getStats: can I just store the values instead of recalculating twice (in the example)?

Note: In this example is not a big deal, but I need to apply that code to a more complex scenario, with more complex stats (standard deviation, variance etc) and using more than 1M values...

Thanks

Comment: So you want to render 1M rows long table to a page?

Comment: Not really, I need to calculate similar stats as the JSFiddle but over much bigger data. And I am concerned that however simple calculation run on huge arrays might affect performance if code is not efficient.

Comment: So calculate it once in the controller and pass.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't know how to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **$watch** to listen for updates to your data structure, then update your variables accordingly.

I've created a [fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huqdf2cn/) to illustrate this, with the code below demonstrating the important bits:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function(scope) {
        return $scope.dogs.length;
    },
    function(oldVal, newVal) {
        console.log('dogs changed');
        $scope.updateStats($scope.getAges());
        $scope.updateAverage();
    });
```

Comment: It took a bit to implement it in my project but it´s working like a charm! Thanks!